# Searching based on members that have a twitter website address

Tags: search, advanced-search, social-media

Is there a way via the advanced search query to return all contacts that have a twitter website address entered?

Currently the only search item appears to just be "Your website" but I cannot see anywhere that just gives the twitter option.

I would have thought that there would be a drop down somewhere in the search criteria. Essentially we just want it the search results to list all contacts that have a twitter social media address listed.

Thanks as always for your help.

........................

Hi, Ive gone through some search build options but it still doesn't seem to pull through any contacts as required. Please see the attached images - One of the contact showing the contact type (Community Group) and the Twitter Website field. The other images are examples of the Search Build criteria

[image]
enter image description here
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi - I tried your first example with the search term of just "twitter" and that didn't work for me either. But "twitter,com" does! Have you tried that? I don't understand your second and third examples. Is "Community Group" a custom record type (Contact Type)?

Comment: Hi Mick, Just tried twitter.com and unfortunately that does not work either. Yes the "Community Group" is a custom contact type where all our community members are held. I thought I would give those searches a go because that is the the contact type thats we want the twitter results for. Any further advice welcome :)

Comment: In the contact rather than community group record type? From your first image it looks as if the twitter websites are attached to the the individual contact record rather than your custom one. But I don't really understand your custom contact type. Presumably you have a custom field that you are searching on. But this wouldn't have the individual twitter websites in them

Answer (score 1):

When you say "return all groups" I presume you mean return all contacts, as I don't see a way to associate a website with a group, but please clarify. From what I can see, there doesn't seem to be an option to search on website at all in Advanced search, but I think you can achieve what you want in Search Builder with

```
record type: contact
field: website
operator: like (or maybe a more precise regex)
value: twitter.com
```

Comment: Hi Mick, Thanks for your comment, yes sorry it will be for all contacts. Thanks for the advise, I will try the search builder and see what results are generated.